# Workflow not working when solution is deployed on other environment

Tags: workflow

I have created a workflow in SPDesigner 2010 which will send mail to admin when a new document is uploaded into document library. It works fine in my standalone machine. I saved it as .wsp solution

But when deployed onto a live machine the mail is not fired. So I went into the workflow section and I am unable to see the workflow at all.

Did I do something wrong? Or is there any other way that the solution should be deployed? Please suggest some solutions.

Note: The AD used in both standalone machine and live machine is same.

Answer (score 1):

After deploying the wsp, you need to activate the workflow feature added by the wsp and then publish the workflow from SharePoint Designer.

Here are [the instructions](http://blog.notionone.com/laurieatkinson/2011/03/17/move-a-custom-spd-workflow-between-environments/).

Comment: Dear Laurie, I am developing it on my machine, and I need to deploy the site using that workflow onto a client machine and I really don't want the client to look "into" the workflow. So does your solution still work in my case?

Comment: If it is a SharePoint Designer workflow, then users with permission to use SPD on the site will be able to view and modify the workflow. You could import your wsp into Visual Studio and package your solution, then deploy a Visual Studio workflow instead.

Answer (score 0):

See whether you have activated the feature

Try this [Steps](http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.com/2010/05/move-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflow.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the Site as WSP? Or did you save the Workflow as SPD. For sure when it is a Site, the Workflow won't be packed into the WSP.

So you have to create again the workflow on the new environment.

Comment: Hello PirateEric, I saved the site as .wsp and deployed it onto a client machine.